# how can i insert invoice number in mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

how can i insert invoice number in table
here is the my complete code

my code insert value

like this

```
---------------------
Id | Name| Invoice No
---------------------
1 | ali    | 
2 | albert | 
3 | ruby   | 
---------------------
```

and i want like this

```
---------------------
Id | Name| Invoice No
---------------------
1 | ali    | 1
2 | albert | 1
3 | ruby   | 1
---------------------
```

how can i do like this please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

i have two file

1st is index.php

```
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title>Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</title>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <div class="container">  
                <br />  
                <br />  
                <h2 align="center">Dynamically Add or Remove input fields in PHP with JQuery</h2>  
                <div class="form-group">  
                     <form name="add_name" id="add_name">  
                          <div class="table-responsive">  
                               <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
                                    <tr>  
                                         <td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td>  
                                         <td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add More</button></td>  
                                    </tr>  
                               </table>  
                               <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                          </div>  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
      $('#add').click(function(){  
           i++;  
           $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Enter your Name" class="form-control name_list" /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
      });  
      $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
           var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
           $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
      });  
      $('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"name.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#add_name').serialize(),  
                success:function(data)  
                {  
                     alert(data);  
                     $('#add_name')[0].reset();  
                }  
           });  
      });  
 });  
 </script>
```

2nd is name.php

```
<?php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");  
 $number = count($_POST["name"]);  
 if($number > 0)  
 {  
      for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++)  
      {  
           if(trim($_POST["name"][$i] != ''))  
           {  
                $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(name) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i])."')";  
                mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
           }  
      }  
      echo "Data Inserted";  
 }  
 else  
 {  
      echo "Please Enter Name";  
 }  
 ?>
```

Comment: Simply insert `Invoice No` is `1` in all insertion ?

Comment: i do not want manual enter of invoice number

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use manual escaping and string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) if you ever forget to properly escape something.

Answer (score 1):

Well, currently the code inserts a single value into the table:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name(name) VALUES('...')
```

If you want to insert into both columns, provide a value for both columns:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_name(name, `Invoice No`) VALUES('...','...')
```

(Of course providing whatever value you want to provide, and whatever data type it should be.)

Basically, do it *exactly the same way you already are*, just with two columns instead of one.  You can read more about the `INSERT` syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html).

Comment: how can script take invoice number automatic

Comment: @msalman: First you'd need to define the rules for *creating* that value.  The only example you provide is the literal number `1`, so you can just use that literal number.  Otherwise, if you want to generate a number based on some set of business logic, you'd first need to define that logic.  "How can I create a number?" isn't really anything we can answer.  Something as simple as `var x = 1;` "creates a number".

Answer (score 0):

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(name) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i])."')";
```

In the above line you are inserting `name` only. Add the `Invoice No` column also in the INSERT statement, so it should be

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(name, `invoice no`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"][$i])."', 1)";
```

Comment: how can script take invoice number automatic